# Limit on number of items in $nin query in mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, shell

I'm doing a query with

```
db.collection.find({'user_id':{$nin:[ObjectId("551555f8772a84cd244d6bb5"), .... ]}});
```

And that fails with 109 items and seems to work with 108.
The error I get is   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL when I try to run this from a file with the command

```
mongo mydb < file.js
```

Is there an undocumented limit? Or is there a way around this?

Comment: Might be a line length limit in the script parser. Is it all on one line in file.js? If so can you break it up over multiple lines?

Comment: JohnnyHK, that seems to do the trick. I will test with all the data and see if it works.

Comment: Yes!! JohnnyHK, your suggestion solved the problem. Thank you! (not sure how to mark your comment as the correct one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is exactly as you've shown it with all the code on one line, it's likely breaking a limit on the line length in the script parser.

Break it up over multiple lines instead:

```
db.collection.find({'user_id':{$nin:[
    ObjectId("551555f8772a84cd244d6bb5"),
    .... 
]}});
```